# $\lim_{n \to +\infty}$ with $\sqrt[n]{\ln(n)}$ (in the example: $n(1 + \sqrt[n]{\ln(n)})$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

So, I found lots of exercises for $\lim_{n \to +\infty}$ with $\sqrt[n]{\ln(n)}$ in my calculus book and I didn't know how to solve those. The example is $\lim_{n \to +\infty} n(1 + \sqrt[n]{\ln(n)})$.

I actually know the limit from this post: [Limit:$ \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left ( n\bigl(1-\sqrt[n]{\ln(n)} \bigr) \right )$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/237446/limit-lim-limits-n-rightarrow-infty-left-n-bigl1-sqrtn-lnn-bigr?fbclid=IwAR1_1HOqFDLNPsStbVZfCarE-933YDSUCNjAK6DHMwXv9dPjR8AQk694BHo). The problem is, all answers use "Taylor, h'Hospital or d'Alembert" and I didn't learn about those theorems yet. So my question is - is there any way to deal with $\lim_{n \to +\infty} \sqrt[n]{\ln(n)}$ (taking $\lim_{n \to +\infty} n(1 + \sqrt[n]{\ln(n)})$ as an example) using most basic calculus?

By most basic calculus I mean not using Taylor, h'Hospital nor d'Alembert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a hint:

For $n\geq e^2$

$$
e^{1/n}<(\log n)^{1/n}\leq n^{1/n}
$$

There are several "elementary" methods to show that

1. $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}p^{1/n}=1$ for $p>0$ constant and
2. $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}n^{1/n}=1$
   See for instance Rudin's  Principle's of mathematical analysis, p. 57.

The conclusion follows from the squeeze lemma.

Proofs for [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/488014/how-can-one-prove-that-lim-n-to-inftya1-n-1-for-every-a0?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/154188/121671)  type of methods also have been explained on this site.

Comment: Thank you Oliver! I need to think more often in terms of squeeze lemma.